# .Net Entity synchronization with SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity, synchronization

I am currently implementing a system using Entity over SQL Server, and I was wondering if there was a way to fully synchronize the Entity objects with the SQL Server database.

For instance

Application A :
Connect the contexts etc..

Application B :
Updates some data in the database (with or without Entity)

Application A :
Is notified of the changes and impact the entity objects

Thanks

Comment: "Entity over SQL Server" ??? Do you mean the ADO.NET **Entity Framework** ??

Answer (score 0):

As a quick answer, take a look at the [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class - it can provide notifications of updates to data you have selected, which sounds to be what you want.  If this is what you want to do, then I've no doubt that you can wire up the entity framework stack to plug these in.

However, you would be much better off taking alook at a few articles concerning [Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx) and contemplating mechanics for Pessimistic or Optimistic Concurrency, both of which the Framework is capable of OOB.